Modify data before applying the filter in PostgreSQL
I'm using PostgreSQL for storing the data. It is linked with Spring boot as application server. I'm using JPA to access the data.
Now, I have a entity named custom_user with string property mobile_number. The format of mobile_number is +{{country_code}}.{{actual_number}} (ex. +91.123, +92.456). Now, I want to filter this records using search queries such as "+91", "123", "+91123", "+924".
I tried following query but it is not working
SELECT ma.*
FROM custom_user cu
AND (
  cu.mobile_number LIKE CONCAT(:mobileNumber, '.%') 
  OR (
    cu.mobile_number REGEXP CONCAT('^\\+', '[0-9]*\\.?', '[0-9]*')  
    AND (
      cu.mobile_number LIKE CONCAT(:mobileNumber, '.%')  
      OR REPLACE(cu.mobile_number, '.', '') LIKE CONCAT(REPLACE(:mobileNumber, '+', ''), '.%')  
    )
  )
)


"Is not working" is not accurate enough. At first sight, the query has syntactical errors. It has no "where" clause. Can you correct that? You mention you're using JPA with Spring Boot, where do you put this query? JPQL? Native SQL query? What do you mean with "modify data before applying the filter"? Which data exactly? Please, improve your question providing a code example if you can. I hope it helps!
